file_get_contents через раз читает ресурс
Столкнулся с проблемой - file_get_contents через раз читает ресурс.
Запускается чтение файлов в цикле по url, файлы существуют точно.
Некоторые вызовы file_get_contents падают с ворнингом : failed to open stream: operation failed.
При втором запуске - все читается. И так рендомно, то читается - то нет.
Как это можно объяснить ?

Вероятно файл кем-то ещё записывается. Или два одновременных запроса что-то поделить не могут, хотя странно, если ты на чтение открываешь - флаги блокировки не добавлял?

@MikhailZhuikov если вы не знаете, как метод file_get_contents описан в коде, то вам скорее всего не стоит обращать внимание на этот вопрос


Получить актуальный ответ сервера, как написано по ссылке сверху. 2. Вывести $http_response_header


Да, сорее всего вы правы, одновременный запрос к одному ресурсу ,идет параллельно работа несколько одинаковых скриптов во одним и тем же спискам ссылок. Вот пример (список проверенный все ссылки валидные перед запросом) <?php
$urlList = file("url_list.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($urlList as $key => $value) {
if (!empty($value)) {
    $content = file_get_contents($value);
}    

}
?>

Это конечно очень умная стратегия. Не только присосаться к чужому сервису, но еще и убивать его в процессе.
